# Pandas dataframe "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" when using .apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 3884 rows × 4458 columns and filled with numbers. I'm trying to equate numbers greater than 1 to 1. I have tried

```
df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 1 else 0)
```

Or I tried to make function but I'm getting this error.

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I checked previous topics and see many questions about this but I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `x >= 1` returns a series of True/False values based on the original numeric value, because `x` is a series representing a column inside your lambda.

You could use `(x >= 1).all()` or `any()` or such but that won't suit your needs.

Instead you may use the below to transform each value in the df:

```
df.apply(lambda x : [1 if e >= 1 else 0 for e in x])
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) will apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame. Thus `x` in your lambda is a Series which couldn't be feed into `if` after comparing.

> I'm trying to equate numbers greater than 1 to 1.

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which apply a function to a Dataframe elementwise.

```py
df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x >= 1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ynjxsjmh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913288/4518341) is good, but in this situation, you don't actually need to use `.apply()` in the first place. Pandas and NumPy have more powerful tools for doing this sort of thing. Here are some examples.

Firstly, some example data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-1, 0, 1, 2], 'b': [0, 0, 5, -2]})
>>> df
   a  b
0 -1  0
1  0  0
2  1  5
3  2 -2
```

If like you say, you want to cap numbers at 1, you could use:

- [`.clip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

  ```
  >>> df.clip(upper=1)
     a  b
  0 -1  0
  1  0  0
  2  1  1
  3  1 -2
  ```
- [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

  ```
  >>> df.mask(df>=1, 1)
     a  b
  0 -1  0
  1  0  0
  2  1  1
  3  1 -2
  ```

Or if like your code says, you also want to make numbers 0 if they're less than 1, you could use:

- A comparison on the whole dataframe, then convert the bools to int:

  ```
  >>> df.ge(1).astype(int)
     a  b
  0  0  0
  1  0  0
  2  1  1
  3  1  0
  ```

  - Docs: [`.ge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html)
- [`numpy.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

  ```
  >>> df[:] = np.where(df>=1, 1, 0)
  >>> df
     a  b
  0  0  0
  1  0  0
  2  1  1
  3  1  0
  ```

Comment: P.S. I'm not a NumPy/Pandas expert. I know there are probably even more powerful functions like maybe [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) or [`numpy.digitize()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html), but I'm not sure how to make them work. I'm open to suggestions.